# Injecting dependencies into @RestController in Spring-Boot using xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have basic controller

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    private RegisterService registerService;

    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity registerUser(){
    }
}
```

I want to use XML configuration for bean definition in my spring-boot app. I am using:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:/config/context.xml")
public class SplitBillApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SplitBillApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

However how do i define @RestController in this config? When i simply do

```
<bean id="loginController" class="com.splitbill.login.controller.LoginController">
    <property name="registerService" ref="registerService"/>
</bean>
```

However @RestController probably does indeed create same bean so code above throws error about bean already existing.

I don't mind the controllers being created by component scan or something, however i want to create service with XML config and inject it. Is somethinglike that possible? Or how can i define config for @RestControllers using XML?

Thanks for help!

Comment: *I want to use XML configuration for bean definition in my spring-boot app.* Why do you want that?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- i feel more comfortable using that, and i am used  to XML configuration

Comment: I would suggest that you learn Java configuration. It's almost entirely replaced XML in new development, and you're going to need to be familiar with it in the future. In particular auto-configuration is all JavaConfig.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error due to the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation already perform the component scan for you and therefor the `@RestController` annotated bean is already built by spring.

Anyway in order to leverage of all spring mvc capabilities you should use annotation driven approach, I talking about spring mvc stuff.
Then if you are more comfortable to use old xml way you can use your approach for service layer but not for mvc.

During my job I saw some one that was able to configure rest controller stuff in java config but i discourage this practice

p.s.

@RestController annotation definition:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestController {
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Controller.class
    )
    String value() default "";
}
```

this annotation is a sterotype annotation there fore @SpringBootApplication load all those bean.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(
    excludeFilters = {@Filter(
    type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
    classes = {TypeExcludeFilter.class}
), @Filter(
    type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
    classes = {AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class}
)}
)
public @interface SpringBootApplication {
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = EnableAutoConfiguration.class
    )
    Class<?>[] exclude() default {};

    @AliasFor(
        annotation = EnableAutoConfiguration.class
    )
    String[] excludeName() default {};

    @AliasFor(
        annotation = ComponentScan.class,
        attribute = "basePackages"
    )
    String[] scanBasePackages() default {};

    @AliasFor(
        annotation = ComponentScan.class,
        attribute = "basePackageClasses"
    )
    Class<?>[] scanBasePackageClasses() default {};

    @AliasFor(
        annotation = ComponentScan.class,
        attribute = "nameGenerator"
    )
    Class<? extends BeanNameGenerator> nameGenerator() default BeanNameGenerator.class;

    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Configuration.class
    )
    boolean proxyBeanMethods() default true;
}
```

as you can see @SpringBootAnnotation is capable to do component scan starting from the package of the annotated application class recursively in depth